# Select multiple counts from one database table in one sql command

Tags: sql, database, oracle, select, count

I have a Oracle database table like so, which records an item being scanned at a scanning point.

> **ItemsScan**
>   *ItemScanId*
>   *ItemScanPoint*
>   *ItemType*
>   *ScanTime*

I want to return the ItemScanPoint along with the number of times a specific ItemType was scanned at that ItemScanPoint.

Something along the lines of..

```
SELECT ItemScanPoint,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) WHERE ItemType = 1),
       (SELECT COUNT(*) WHERE ItemType = 2)
FROM   ItemsScan
```

How do I do this in oracle?

What is the most efficient way?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
SELECT   ItemScanPoint,
         SUM(CASE ItemType WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) ,
         SUM(CASE ItemType WHEN 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)   
FROM     ItemsScan 
GROUP BY ItemScanPoint
```

Comment: @endorphin, This is probably the best solution as CASE is standard SQL but it would also FYI be possible to use the Oracle DECODE() function, e.g., `SUM(DECODE(ItemType, 1, 1, 0)), SUM(DECODE(ItemType, 2, 1, 0))`. Might save some keystrokes if you don't need a portable solution.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```
select count(ItemScanId), itemscanpoint, itemtype
from itemsscan
where itemtype in (1,2)
group by itemtype, itemscanpoint
```

Comment: I'm more after an SQL command which will have a select command of the form  `select itemscanpoint, count(itemType1), count(itemType2), count(itemTypeX)`. So that the item scan point name and all counts are returned in one record.

Comment: @endorphin: of the form...what?

Comment: Sorry, did not realise Enter submits the comment. I've editted the original.

Answer (score 0):

Count is a grouping function in oracle.  Try this:

```
select
 ItemType,
 count(ItemType)
from
 ItemsScan
group by
 ItemType
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible to do this using COUNT() as an analytic function as well:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ItemScanPoint, ItemType
     , COUNT(ItemScanId) OVER (PARTITION BY ItemScanPoint, ItemType)
  FROM ItemsScan
```

It will return the data in a different format than that asked in the OP but it will return results for **all** values of `ItemType` rather than just two.

Hope this helps.